# Google Maps JavaScript API RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We're trying to develop an geoplacement app for one of our clients, and we want first to test it in out own domain.

We have signed for Google Maps JavaScript API, and we have a valid browser key and our domain, www.grupocamaleon.com, has been authorized to use that key.

But we can't make even the easiest example to run without error.

We have, in our domain and with our key, the following demo:

(1) http://www.grupocamaleon.com/boceto/aerial-simple.html

But it doesn't work, and Firebug console says:

"Google Maps API error: Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError (link to Google documentation on RefererNotAllowedMapError) Your site URL to be authorized: (1)"

My credential page is missing the possibility of adding referrers to accept, so solutions involving adding referrers are not possible right now.

My credential Page:

[image]

Why do we get that error? How can we fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps API referrer not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600314/google-maps-api-referrer-not-allowed).  [Your code works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_45degreeImagery_KeyError.html) (with my key), so there is something wrong with your key, the allowed referrers, or the services enabled to use with it.

Comment: But I have not such possibility in my credentials page, as you can see in my answer here. Any hint?

Comment: Well, I'm a newbie and I don't know how to use this site corrently yet. Sorry for the inconveniences.

I've edited my question, adding information on my credential page. Some solutions cited involve adding referrers, what I can not do at the moment.

Comment: If you can't change the referrers for the key, remove it or replace it with one you control.  A key is not required, but there are benefits to including one.

Comment: I created new key with no APP or API restrictions, it said expiredKey for 10 minutes, then started working. Next I tried adding just Places API, but it is being called from web and says: `Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError` even after waiting. Then I tried `Maps JavaScript API` and it kept saying `RefererNotAllowedMapError`, tried refreshing the page and it finally started to work after 2 minutes and 40 seconds. So watch the hell out. But WITHOUT anything DOES work for me, and so does `Maps JavaScript API` only. You just have to wait a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to **clear the browser cache** after making changes - this killed my time

Comment: and **Note:** It may take up to **5 minutes** for settings to take effect

Comment: Regenerating the key has worked for me.

Answer (score 217):

I know this is an old question that already has several answers, but I had this same problem and for me the issue was that I followed the example provided on console.developers.google.com and entered my domains in the format `*.domain.tld/*`. This didn't work at all, and I tried adding all kinds of variations to this like `domain.tld`, `domain.tld/*`, `*.domain.tld` etc.

What solved it for me was adding the actual *protocol* too; `http://domain.tld/*` is the only one I need for it to work on my site. I guess I'll need to add `https://domain.tld/*` if I were to switch to HTTPS.

Update: Google have finally updated the placeholder to include `http` now:

[image: Google Maps API referrer input field]

Comment: I confirm: the only combination that allowed me the use of the API was `http://www.---.com/*`

Comment: This answer is the only one that got my code working. I can confirm that the example that Google provides does not work.

Comment: Thank you, @Google, for giving us false information. **http://----.com/*** is the correct format.

Comment: If you have multiple sub domains you can do, http://*.example.com and https://*.example.com to cover all bases

Comment: Maybe Google updated that feature – for me it works without the protocol. I have `example.com/*` in the settings field, and it works from `https://example.com/map`

Comment: I can confirm, too: This in combination with domain.com/*/* finally got it working for me, too.

Comment: I'm trying to get my test environment working with the url http://test.localdomain:8000/. Nothing, literally nothing works. Not even removing any restriction works. I always get the `RefererNotAllowedMapError` error. Restricting to my local IP doesn't work either. I'm helpless.

Comment: @karolyi did you try the answer above? Ie adding the protocol? Local domains always work fine for me.

Comment: @powerbuoy yes I did. I tried every possible combination, nothing worked. hence, I created a bug in their issue system.

Comment: my ionic mobile app has domain as ionic://app#/tabs. How would I include it in the restrictions. I tried many combinations but in vain. Ex: ionic://app#/tabs, httpionic://app#/tabs, httpsionic://app#/tabs, ionic://*, ionic://app#/*, httpionic://*, ......

Comment: `*.example/*` works. I set the wrong API restriction. I Used Places instead of Maps Javascript API for Autocomplete.

Comment: So many years after, the only thing working for me is separate entries `http://example.com/*`, `http://www.example.com/*` etc.

Comment: I have some old domains that work without the protocol. But for this new website, it only worked after I added https://

Comment: Finally the best answer of all responses that I read

Answer (score 32):

Come on Google, you guys are smarter than the API Credential page lets on.  (I know because I have two sons working there.)

The list of "referrers" is far pickier than it lets on.  (Of course, it *should* be more forgiving.)  Here are some rules that took me *hours* to discover:

- The order in the list is important.  Moving your URL up in the list may make it work.
- "http://" prefix is required.
- Even "localhost" needs it:  "http://localhost/foo/bar.html"
- A *trailing* `*` as a wildcard seems to work as if it is a string compare.
- Even with "http://localhost/foo/bar.html", "http://localhost/foo/bar.html?arg=1" will not work.  (Will a wildcard help?)
- For both prod dev, have (at least) two rows: "http://localhost/foo/bar.html" and "http://my.site.com/foo/bar.html"
- A port number (8085? 4000?) does not seem to be necessary.

There are probably other rules, but this is a tedious guessing game.

Comment: About the answer before the edit, I'm running out of patience too. Looks like that wildacards (*) only work in the end of an address (`http://my.site.com/*`) or in in a subdomain (`http://*.site.com`). In ALL the other cases it doesn't work

Comment: I had incorrectly put a restriction to only allow the Places API (the tab right next to the referrer restrictions). This results in the same RefererNotAllowedMapError error.

Comment: Adding www. to my domain name fixed it for me.   I am not sure if adding a wildcard (*) to the end of domain, such as `(https://www.my-site.com/*)` has also corrected the issue.

Comment: my ionic mobile app has domain as ionic://app#/tabs. How would I include it in the restrictions. I tried many combinations but in vain. Ex: ionic://app#/tabs, httpionic://app#/tabs, httpsionic://app#/tabs, ionic://*, ionic://app#/*, httpionic://*, ......

Comment: @AUK4SO - The pound sign (`#`) has a special meaning in urls.  See `<a name=...>`.  Or did you mean `iconic://1234/foo`?

Comment: @RickJames - Yea, I mean my server url is ionic://app

Comment: Moving my domain up in the list is what fixed it for me… Really, Google?

Comment: @AUK4SO - did you ever get this to work for the ionic app?  I am using Javascript Map API in my app and am having a devil of a time figuring out the correct restriction url.  The console error I am getting is: `Your site URL to be authorized: __file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html#/tab/map////` - thus what is my referrer url supposed to be?  Is it `http://localhost/index.html` or `http://localhost/index.html#/tab/map/` or `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/tab/map////`  - I am stumped on this.

Comment: @RickJames - any insight into my question for auk4so above?

Comment: @rolinger
Google treats http or https as valid protocols. I suggest you to check the "ionic-cordova-webview" plugin version. Go with the latest version >=4.0.
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Answer (score 29):

Wildcards (asterisks) **ARE NOT** allowed in the subdomain part.

- **WRONG:** *.example.com/*
- **RIGHT:** example.com/*

Forget what Google says on the placeholder, it is not allowed.

Comment: How can I add the following then: https://sc.maindomain.com/Survey/UpdateInspection/102

Comment: You can set as `sc.maindomain.com/*`

Comment: `*.example.com/*` also works

Comment: thank you! google still has the wrong documentation up!

Answer (score 23):

Just remind that if you just change it, it may take up to 5 minutes for settings to take effect.

Answer (score 20):

According to the documentation, 'RefererNotAllowedMapError' means

> The current URL loading the Google Maps JavaScript API has not been
>   added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer
>   settings of your API key on the Google Developers Console.

I have the Google Maps Embed API set up for my own personal/work use and thus far have not specified any HTTP referrers. I register no errors. Your settings must be making Google think the URL you're visiting is not registered or allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I tried many referrer variations and waiting 5 minutes as well until I realized the example Google populates in the form field is flawed. They show:

```
*.example.com/*
```

However that only works if you have `subdomain.` or `www.` in front of your domain name. The following worked for me immediately (omitting the leading period from Google's example):

```
*example.com/*
```

Comment: Bad idea - someone could create `hackexample.com` and use your api

Comment: @HyderA - A more likely possibility is that someone would register a bunch free google accounts to get extra map loads.

Comment: @HyderA they would still need the key, so not a huge chance.  But you're right, still a potential risk.

Comment: my ionic mobile app has domain as ionic://app#/tabs. How would I include it in the restrictions. I tried many combinations but in vain. Ex: ionic://app#/tabs, httpionic://app#/tabs, httpsionic://app#/tabs, ionic://*, ionic://app#/*, httpionic://*, ......

Answer (score 14):

According the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages)
this happened because  the `url` on which you  are using the Google Maps API, it `not registered` in `list of allowed referrers`

EDIT :

From [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#registering-authorized-urls)

> **All subdomains of a specified domain are also authorized.**
>
> If http://example.com is authorized, then http://www.example.com is also authorized. The reverse is not true: if http://www.example.com is authorized, http://example.com is not necessarily authorized

So,Please configure `http://testdomain.com` domain, then your `http://www.testdomain.com` will start work.

Comment: In my case it was misconfigured DNS for the domain.  For example:

www.testdomain.com worked fine

testdomain.com didn't work causing an error

Comment: It would seem the logic of that is reversed? Unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 11):

Check you have the correct APIS enabled as well.

I tried all of the above, asterisks, domain tlds, forward slashes, backslashes and everything, even in the end only entering one url as a last hope.

All of this did not work and finally I realised that Google also requires that you specify now which API's you want to use (see screenshot)

[image]

I did not have ones I needed enabled (for me that was Maps JavaScript API)

Once I enabled it, all worked fine using:

http://www.example.com/*

I hope that helps someone! :)

Answer (score 9):

There are lots of supposed solutions accross several years, and some don’t work any longer and some never did, thus my up-to-date take working per end of July 2018.

**Setup:**

Google Maps JavaScript API has to work properly with…

- multiple domains calling the API: `example.com` and `example.net`
- arbitrary subdomains: `user22656.example.com`, etc.
- both secure and standard HTTP protocols: `http://www.example.com/` and `https://example.net/`
- indefinite path structure (i.e. a large number of different URL paths)

**Solution:**

- Actually using the pattern from the placeholder: `<https (or) http>://*.example.com/*`.
- Not omitting the protocol, but adding two entries per domain (one per protocol).
- An additional entry for subdomains (with a `*.` leading the hostname).
- I had the feeling that the `RefererNotAllowedMapError` error still appeared using the proper configuration (and having waited ample time). I deleted the credential key, repeated the request (now getting `InvalidKeyMapError`), created new credentials (using the exact same setup), and it worked ever since.
- Adding mere protocol and domain seemed not to have included subdomains.
- For one of the domains, the working configuration looks like this:

[image: Screenshot from Google API configuration]

*(As text:)*

```
Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)
    https://*.example.com/*
    https://example.com/*
    http://*.example.com/*
    http://example.com/*
```

Comment: In my case, this solution helped but had API Restriction on the wrong API. For some reason, the same error message was returned. Changing API Restriction from 'Places API' to 'Maps Javascript API' fixed the issue.

Comment: deleting the key and creating a new one worked for me

Answer (score 9):

**The Problem**
Google suggests the format `*.example.com/*`
This format does not work.

**The Solution**
Check the browser console for the Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
Underneath the error it should have: "Your site URL to be authorized: [https://example.com/"](https://example.com/%22).
Use that url for the referrer and add a wildcard * to the end of it (https://example.com/*, in this case).

Comment: Hey I tried this and every other variation I've found on SO without any luck. Did something change in 2021?

Comment: In 2022 this answer is working. `https://yoursite.com/*` , `https://*.yoursite.com/*`  You must add both of these. This should be work.

Comment: `*example.com/*` also works

Answer (score 8):

I found that even your `HTTP Referreres` are valid enough, wrong set of `API Restrictions` causes `Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError`.

For example:

- You are using Javascript API for the key.
- Add `http://localhost/*` to `Application Restrictions / HTTP Referrences`
- Choose `Maps Embed API` instead of `Maps Javascript API`
- This causes `RefererNotAllowedMapError`

Comment: Yes, in my case misclassification was the issue

Comment: But what about the security? Can anyone use my key in localhost if I allowed for localhost ?

Answer (score 8):

None of these fixes were working for me until I found out that `RefererNotAllowedMapError` can be caused by not having a billing account linked to the project. So make sure to activate your free trial or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

This is another sh1tty Google product with a terrible implemenation.

The problem I have found with this is that if you restrict an API key by IP address, it wont work... BUT far be it from Google to make this point clear... It wasn't until troubleshooting and researching I found:

> API keys with an IP addresses restriction can only be used with web
>   services that are intended for use from the server side (such as the
>   Geocoding API and other Web Service APIs). Most of these web services
>   have equivalent services within the Maps JavaScript API (for example,
>   see the Geocoding Service). To use the Maps JavaScript API client side
>   services, you will need to create a separate API key which can be
>   secured with an HTTP referrers restriction (see Restricting an API
>   key).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

FFS Google... Pretty important piece of information that would be good to clarify on setup...

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)**

Write localhost directory path

Comment: according to Google's text it is supposed to be an optional property and if it blank it should work

Comment: @ayanchakraborty - I have tried 10 different combinations of http://localhost/index.html (and various paths) as well as various combinations of file:///android_assets/www/index.html - but nothing is working. The RefererNotAllowedMapError in console is showing me: Your site URL to be authorized: __file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html#/tab/map////` - but this and variations don't work either.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same error:

[image]

This link talks about how to set up API key restrictions: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_http_restrictions

In my case, the problem was that I was using this restriction:

> HTTP referrers (web sites) Accept requests from these HTTP referrers
>   (web sites) (Optional) Use *'s for wildcards. If you leave this blank,
>   requests will be accepted from any referrer. Be sure to add referrers
>   before using this key in production.
>   `https://*.example.net/*`

This means that URLs such as https://www.example.net or https://m.example.net or https://www.example.net/San-salvador/ would work. However, URLs such as https://example.net or https://example.net or https://example.net/San-salvador/ would not work. I simply needed to add a second referrer:

> `https://example.net/*`

That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I add 2 website domains, set "*" in subdomain is not working but specific subdomain "WWW" and non-subdomain have been worked for my websites using the same Google Map API key.

[dont' use "*" in subdomain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mmPH.png)

Hope it help.

Answer (score 4):

1. That your billing is enabled
2. That your website has been added to *Google Console*
3. That your website is added to the referrers in your app.
4. (do a wildcard for both www and none www)

http://www.example.com/*  and http://example.com/*

5. That Javascript Maps is enabled and you are using the correct credentials
6. That the website has been added to your DNS to enable your Google Console above.
7. Smile after it works!

Comment: Your list of allowed referrers can be found in Google Cloud Platform web console (console.cloud.google.com) under `APIs & Services > Credentials > (your key) > Application restrictions > HTTP Referrers`

Answer (score 4):

Enable billing for Google project fixed the problem.

Comment: This was also the case for me. @Darren Murphy is not correct in that the *.example.com/* does not work.

Answer (score 3):

you show a screenshot of your api credentials page, but you have to click on "Browser key 1" and go from there to add referrers.

Answer (score 3):

**For deeper nested pages**

If you have a project in a folder for example or nested pages

`http://yourdomain.com/your-folder/your-page` you can enter this in

`http://yourdomain.com/*/*`

The important part being `/*/*/*` depending how far you need to go

It seems that the `*` will not match `/` or get into deeper paths..

This will give your full domain access, well unless you have deeper nesting than that..

Answer (score 3):

I struggled to make this work as well, but here are some pointers:

- The URLs set as referrers include `http`, e.g. `http://example.com/*`
- Google Maps JavaScript API was enabled
- Billing was set-up on this account

Once all of this above was resolved, the maps displayed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.example.com/* has worked for me after  days and days of trying.

Answer (score 2):

I got mine working finally by using this tip from Google: 
(https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179)

Here are our definitions of domain and site. These definitions are specific to Search Console verification:

```
http://example.com/ - A site (because it includes the http:// prefix)
example.com/ - A domain (because it doesn't include a protocol prefix)
puppies.example.com/ - A subdomain of example.com
http://example.com/petstore/ - A subdirectory of http://example.com site
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your declaration on site. To load the Google Maps JavaScript API, use a script tag like this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

I using this declaration on my Wordpress site in function.php file

```
wp_enqueue_script("google-maps-v3", "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY", false, array(), false, true);
```

I have set API key on this format, and its works fine

```
http://my-domain-name(without www).com/*
```

this declaration not working

```
*.my-domain-name.com/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting to use the **Places API (Autocomplete)** and had to also enable the **Maps Javascript API** from within Google Cloud Console before the Places API would work.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the restrictions (to None) worked for me.

Comment: removing the restrictions is considered bad practice and makes your API vulnerable.

Comment: @mtness yes obviously but the poster has already tried it first without success. Unfortunately Google's documentation isn't any more helpful. Every answer here are bringing in new tips, it's almost like a guessing game...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience

> http://www.example.com

worked fine
But, https required /* at the end

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's Javascript console suggested I declare the entire page address in my HTTP referrer list, in this instance http://mywebsite.com/map.htm Even though the exact address is http://www.mywebsite.com/map.htm - I already had wildcard styles listed as suggested by others but this was the only way it would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. There are 2 major categories of restrictions under api key settings:

- `Application restrictions`
- `API restrictions`

[Google API KEY Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

### Application restrictions:

> At the bottom in the Referrer section add your website url
> " http://www.grupocamaleon.com/boceto/aerial-simple.html " .There are example rules on the right hand side of the section based on various requirements.

[image: Application restrictions]

### API restrictions:

> Under API restrictions you have to explicitly select **'Maps Javascript API'** from the dropdown list since our unique key will only be used for calling the Google maps API(probably) and save it as you can see in the below snap. I hope this works for you.....worked for me

[image]

### Check your Script:

Also the issue may arise due to improper key feeding inside the script tag. It should be something like:

```
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `jskey` must match the key under Google Dashboard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on localhost then do not include http or https in the url.

Use "localhost" without protocols. I struggled for days and found it working.

Answer (score 0):

Something no one else seems to have mentioned in here that may be important is also this:

Http referrers are **case sensitive**.

So say you have someone access https://www.example.com/webpage, and someone wrote a link to that page as https://www.example.com/Webpage, you need BOTH entries, otherwise one of them is not going to work (unless you URL-rewrite to remove caps, or replace /Webpage with /*, but in our case, we want to limit down to folders under a certain domain, so this is a pain in the butt).

I feel like this is a bit stupid. Yes, URLs can be case sensitive, but not to the point where you would restrict a folder if its in caps, but not if it's lowercase, right?

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct answer I have found for this as of writing is to use `*example.com/*`