# This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.before that showed map in 2s

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using this code from google map API's and entered the API key, but still get the above mentioned error

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<style>
   #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
}
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() {
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       center: { lat: 10.523900, lng: 76.212250 },
       zoom: 8
        });
      }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAi6Ztik8PTvZFBFieP0k7aVWGMdNGHJ9c&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: What do the _"technical details"_ say?

Comment: Error define itself about the issue but unfortunately no error is showing in the console

Comment: yes! Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://localhost:52194/User/Map

Answer (score 0):

Update: It looks like your code is fine. I think this is an issue with the way you configure your site setting in google developer console - have a look at [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288250/google-maps-javascript-api-referernotallowedmaperror).

It entails making sure you enter your domain wildcard properly (`http://www.example.com/*`) and enabling the required APIs (`Maps JavaScript API`).

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: yes, i solved that error. but now showing "billing account" error. Is there any way to get api key at free of cost?