# Google Map doesn't show up anything

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

Google Map doesn't up at this website, http://165.232.77.75:8080/contact.html. It doesn't load up properly though I already replace the real API key. I even already configured properly in Restrict and rename API key at Google Cloud Platform. Btw, this is simple static site. It has nothing to do with backend & database. Here's my code:

```
               <script>
                    function initMap() {
                        var uluru = {
                            lat: -25.363,
                            lng: 131.044
                        };
                        var grayStyles = [{
                            featureType: "all",
                            stylers: [{
                                saturation: -90
                            }, {
                                lightness: 50
                            }]
                        }, {
                            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                            stylers: [{
                                color: '#ccdee9'
                            }]
                        }];
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            center: {
                                lat: -31.197,
                                lng: 150.744
                            },
                            zoom: 9,
                            styles: grayStyles,
                            scrollwheel: false
                        });
                    }
                </script>
                <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQSuGVy_L5m4vVVI55pm_X8I1Y0MDk72s&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And, images of messages, "Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details." at the website and also images of Restrict and rename API key.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WxF7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqoX6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyZ3B.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnWwQ.png)

Comment: see the error? `15:04:56.471 Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://165.232.77.75:8080/contact.html js:70:449` that's something you need to fix in your googol account

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288250/google-maps-javascript-api-referernotallowedmaperror

Comment: your googol api key in the request is `AIzaSyDpfS1oRGreGSBU5HHjMmQ3o5NLw7VdJ6I` - but .... according to your screenshots, your googol API key is `AIzaSyBQSuGVy_L5m4vVVI55pm_X8I1Y0MDk72s` - so ....

Comment: I already changed the API Key but it still showing up the error.. @JaromandaX

Comment: Ok, i will check it out. Thx! @nmanikiran

Comment: huh? your requests are STILL using `AIzaSyDpfS1oRGreGSBU5HHjMmQ3o5NLw7VdJ6I` - so ... you haven't succeeded - you also have many other errors in that page

Comment: No, im using this API Key: AIzaSyBQSuGVy_L5m4vVVI55pm_X8I1Y0MDk72s... @JaromandaX

Comment: @nmanikiran I set it to IP addresses in Application restrictions at Google Cloud Platform. Not HTTP referrers.

Comment: I will go through here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error%20Your%20site%20URL%20to%20be%20authorized:%20http://165.232.77.75:8080/contact.html%20js:70:449 Thx, @JaromandaX