# Does Google Maps API work on Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

I'm hosting a website on GitHub pages but I keep getting the error 'referrer not allowed' when I try to load the Google Maps API script. I've added the page's URL to the API console (and I've tried lots of variations) and it keeps saying the same thing.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Looks like you have to recreate the API key after changing the allowed domains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600314/google-maps-api-referrer-not-allowed

Answer (score 4):

Recreating the API key at https://console.developers.google.com will fix the issue. And use your current GitHub pages domain URL to generate the API key